# MySQL replication working, but data is out of date

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.1

I'm trying to figure out why even though `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` isn't reporting any errors, nothing is replicating (see below):

both nodes are running:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+------------+
| VERSION()  |
+------------+
| 5.1.73-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

on

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
#
```

master:

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            File: mysql-bin.000107
        Position: 228679653
    Binlog_Do_DB: 
Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified

mysql>
```

slave:

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: MASTER_HOST
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000107
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 228681259
               Relay_Log_File: mysql:PR_DB-relay-bin.000150
                Relay_Log_Pos: 228398599
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000107
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: DB1,DB2,DB3,DB4
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: information_schema,mysql
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 228681259
              Relay_Log_Space: 228681667
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified

mysql>
```

master:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB3.users;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    97786 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

slave:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB3.users;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    95678 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

at the initial time of setting up replication, `SELECT COUNT(*)` returned same values.

Comment: `Replicate-*-DB` options, and others like them that prevent replicating the entire server are *extremely* problematic unless you absolutely understand how they work and their implications, especially when the master's `binlog_format` is not set to `ROW`.  Have you read and thoroughly understood [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-rules.html) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-rules-db-options.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

due to:

[MySQL :: MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: 16.1.3.3 Replication Slave Options and Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db)

```
Warning

To specify multiple databases you must use multiple instances of this option. Because database names can contain commas, if you supply a comma separated list then the list will be treated as the name of a single database.
```

`my.cnf`'s incorrect syntax:

`--replicate-do-db=DB1,DB2,DB3,DB4`

was replaced with correct syntax:

```
--replicate-do-db=DB1
--replicate-do-db=DB2
--replicate-do-db=DB3
--replicate-do-db=DB4
```